# copy rig guide tools

Tags: rigging

I'm new to this world I would like to ask you for help, I am using the latest version of Blender, is there a tool or guide that copies or transfers the rig or reinforcement from one mesh to another? Thank you

Comment: Hello could you please explain the situation more in details?

Comment: I have two identical meshes, one with the rig and the other not I would move the IG between the two.

Comment: if you want to transfer the vertex groups from another mesh, look into the Data Transfer modifier, then give an Armature modifier to the object and parent to the armature with the Armature Deform option?